# When asking a question, enforce user to read the FAQ first

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Is it possible, that when asking a question, a kind of a check to say something like

Tick here, and ***Yes, I have read the FAQ and acknowledge that the question fits the criteria*** in order to enforce the user to *read* the darn thing prior to posting.

All too often OPs are *not* actually reading the FAQ hence getting shot-down with vote-close and saying its *off-topic*...

Comment: Alright :D Seeing your answer below linking to Meta's SO question, it got downvoted 10 times SO, let the downvotes begin :P (jk)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't work.

Like we all do with EULAs, they'll tick the box without reading and keep going.  If there's any fanciness like a timer or making sure they scroll the page, they'll just cheat it and still not read it.

There are already lots of pointers to the FAQ and asking guidelines when you post here for the first time.  (Log out and take a look!)  We can do our best to make sure that content is available and helpful, but we can't do anything about the users who refuse to make use of it.

See also: [Add "I have read the FAQ" check box to the Ask Question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147201/154510) among many others.

Comment: True and fair enough so... /me shrugs...